# Require Authenticated User to Change Password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

Using ASP.Net Forms and ASP.Net MVC 3 (combined - we are in process of changing Web Forms to MVC), I have a scenario where a person authenticates (user name / password) but due to a specific condition existing on their account, they are required to change their password before proceeding.

Since the user is already authenticated, is there a global location where I can prevent any access to the portions of the site that require authentication until they enter their new password? I understand that there might have to be 2 locations (one for Web Forms, the other for MVC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Application_AuthenticateRequest check for the specific condition. If not met (ie they must change pwd), redirect to the proper page. This should work for MVC and WebForms.

Comment: is this method just in the global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom RoleProvider that uses a flag in the user class to determine if the password needs to be changed before validating the role for a user.

Comment: Assuming I check for roles in my application (I don't) - how do I handle this for pages/actions that don't mandate any roles, just that the user is Authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it as a property in the User model (i.e. public bool ChangedPassword {get;set;}). This will be set as False when the user is created, and set as True when the user changes the password. Before any protected action, check if ChangedPassword == True.

Comment: There are several places where I can put the *flag* (cookie, session, etc.) - the question is about where do I put the check for the flag?

Comment: I'm not aware of custom RoleProviders, so if it going to be used in many controllers, you could put it into a partial view, or in _layout.